# Adding an item to a one_to_many relationship in django-tastypie only works the 2nd time

Tags: django, tastypie

Given these models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    # Some fields
    # Some relationship

class ModelB(models.Model):
    # Some fields
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

and these tastypie resources:

```
class ResourceA(ModelResource):
    b_list = fields.ToManyField('app.api.ResourceB', 'a_set', null=True, related_name='a')

class ResourceB(ModelResource):
    a = fields.ToOneField(ResourceA, 'a', null=True)
```

If I visit the detail endpoint for a ResourceB (/api/v1/resourceA/##/) I can see all of the related B's uris - the reverse relationship works. The returned data looks like this:

```
{
    'b_list': [
        '/api/v1/resourceB/1/',
        '/api/v1/resourceB/2/',
    ]
}
```

If I attempt to PUT or PATCH a resource A to add a new B to it, say with this data:

```
{
    'b_list': [
        '/api/v1/resourceB/1/',
        '/api/v1/resourceB/2/',
        '/api/v1/resourceB/3/',
    ]
}
```

I get the error: `'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'add'` with this stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 202, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 449, in dispatch_detail
    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 472, in dispatch
    response = method(request, **kwargs)

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1611, in patch_detail
    self.update_in_place(request, bundle, deserialized)

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1634, in update_in_place
    return self.obj_update(bundle=original_bundle, **kwargs)

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2166, in obj_update
    return self.save(bundle, skip_errors=skip_errors)

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2257, in save
    self.save_m2m(m2m_bundle)

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2382, in save_m2m
    related_resource.save(updated_related_bundle)

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2257, in save
    self.save_m2m(m2m_bundle)

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2382, in save_m2m
    related_resource.save(updated_related_bundle)

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2257, in save
    self.save_m2m(m2m_bundle)

  File \"/home/username/.virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2385, in save_m2m
    related_mngr.add(*related_objs)

AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'add'
```

If I then *immediately* PUT/PATCH the same data, I get no error, no stacktrace, and the item is successfully added to the relationship. I can't figure out why this is the case.

Also, I only seem to be able to add items to the relationship - it would be great to be able to delete them too. I may ask another question about this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is a Django error.
I'm not sure, try to use related_name in the django model.

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
# Some fields
a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name='b_list')
```

Remove the related_name from the resource and the attribute name must change from 'a_set' to 'b_list'

```
class ResourceA(ModelResource):
b_list = fields.ToManyField('app.api.ResourceB', 'b_list', null=True)
```